# Question title spacing

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The space between the question's title and its content is not right and the up-vote arrow is overlapping the respective space. This happens in all major browsers on Mac OS.

See the screenshots below.

Safari:
[image]

Chrome:
[image]

Firefox:
[image]

Comment: This seems to be a problem across a number of sites. I've seen on Webmasters as well.

Comment: [Reported it on Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110945/padding-at-the-top-of-question-bodies-has-gone-missing). Only a few sites still have the padding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed now.

See [this answer on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110945/padding-at-the-top-of-question-bodies-has-gone-missing/110948#110948).